# Async pipe and subscribe on the same Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

I'm using async pipe in my template to get a list of users that match a certain condition (`getNonRedirectingList`). Users are stored in a Firestore instance.

In my component template I have the following (simplified) code:

```
    <div *ngIf="users$ | async as users" class="uwrapper">
        <div *ngFor="let u of users">{{u.name}}</div>
    </div>
```

and this works like a charm: it produces 3 `<div>` blocks, that match the 3 users I'm expecting.

However in the Typescript code I also need to subscribe to the same `Observable` that `@angular/fire` returns

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.users$ = this.userSvc.getNonRedirectingList().pipe(share());
  firstValueFrom(this.users$).then(users => {
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  });
}
```

I'd expect

```
0
1
2
```

as output in the console, but I get nothing instead. Even setting a breakpoint at the `console.log(i)` line, it never gets hit.

I've already tried with and without `.pipe(share())`, I've also tried calling `getNonRedirectingList` twice in the hope of getting two different `Observable` and I've also tried using `subscribe()` and `unsubscribe()` instead of `firstValueFrom()`, but the result was just the same: the async pipe worked, my code did not.

EDIT after S Overflow's answer:

Tried this too, with same results

```
this.users$.pipe(tap(users => {
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}));
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `async` pipe you already subscribe to Observable, so no need of anything else, just append operator, like `tap` to log the values:

`this.users$ = this.userSvc.getNonRedirectingList().pipe(tap(console.log));`

Comment: Thanks, tried, but It still does nothing: the execution flow does not reach `console.log`. Going to edit my question to include this too.

Comment: Updated to set pipe on same instance of your Observable. `pipe` creates a new instance

Answer (score 0):

[CheckThis](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asyncpipe-example-jugzg1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
this.todosList = this.appService.getTodos().pipe(tap((x:any) => {
      x.map(i => console.log(i.id))
    }))
```

Comment: Is this any different from the first answer? Please look at my edited question to clarify, thatnks.

Comment: Its loading data in view using Async and also logging in console. This is ur expection, right?

Comment: Can u check the sample ?